# be wary of vs. be careful about

Tags: difference

What's the difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> He's careful about driving in the fog.

> He's wary of driving in the fog.

Comment: Wary careful because you do not completely trust someone or something or are not certain about what you should do:  https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wary  If he is wary, it means that he doesn't trust his driving abilities in foggy conditions

Comment: (1) He drives carefully when it's foggy. (2) He tries to avoid driving in fog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In real use, there is very little difference.

Someone who is "wary of driving in fog" is indeed primarily going to avoid doing so, but when forced, we can naturally assume that they will do so relatively carefully.

Someone who is "careful about driving in the fog" is clearly doing so because they are wary of it, worried about the dangers it poses.

So: "wary" is the reason, "careful" is the response.